# Swift send compressed video frames using GPUImage

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, video-streaming, gpuimage

I'm writing a Swift app that sends an iPhone camera video input (frames) through the network, so I can later display them on a macOS app.

Currently, I'm grabbing video frames from an `AVCaputreSession`, and get a `PixelBuffer` from the `captureOutput` method.
Since each frame is huge (RAW pixels) I'm converting the `CVPixelBuffer` that to a `CGImage` with `VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer` and later to a `UIImage` with JPEG compression (50%). I then send that JPEG through the network and display it on the Mac OS app.

As you can see this is far from ideal and runs at ~25 FPS on an iPhone 11. After some research, I came up with [GPU Image 2](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2). It seems that I could get the data from the camera and apply something like this (so that the transformation is done in GPU):

```
camera = try Camera(sessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480)
let pictureOutput = PictureOutput()
pictureOutput.encodedImageFormat = .JPEG
pictureOutput.imageAvailableCallback = {image in
    // Send the picture through the network here
}
camera --> pictureOutput
```

And I should be able to transmit that UIImage and display it on the macOS app. Is there a better way to implement this whole process? Maybe I could use the iPhone's H264 hardware encoding instead of converting images to JPEG, but it seems that it's not that straightforward (and it seems that GPUImage does something like that from what I read).

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to do this operation in a non-internet environment.

What are your project constraints;

1. Minimum fps?
2. Minimum video resolution?
3. Should sound be transmitted?
4. What is your network environment?
5. Minimum iOS and OSX version?

Apart from these, GPUImage is not a suitable solution for you. If you are going to transfer videos, you have to encode H264 or H265 (HEVC) in every moment. In this way, you can transmit video in a performance way.

The solution you are doing now is CMSampleBuffer-> CVPixelBuffer-> JPEG-> Data conversion seriously burden the processor. It also increases the risk of memory leak.

If you can tell a little bit, I would like to help. I have experience with video processing.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response. Regarding your questions:
1. At least 30 fps
2. At least 1080
3. If I can transmit the video with audio, that would be awesome. Or at least send it sepparate from the video
4. It's a local environment, so don't worry about that. Assume a really high bandwith
5. We can use the latest versions of both

Yes, compressing things in H264 or H265 would be ideal, but sending that "on the fly" through the network without storing it to the disk (maybe that's the only way) seems to be a nontrivial thing.